# MAth Equation not working properly

Tags: equation, equations, equation-solving

I have been working on a math equation for 2 days.  The whole process is supposed to take the information from a driver and the return the final average.  However, for some reason it is not processing correctly.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
public double Overall() {
    double finalProjectGrade = ((projectGrade1 * 0.1) + (projectGrade2 * 0.1) + (projectGrade3 * 0.1) + (projectGrade4 * 0.1));            
    double finalQuizGrade = ((quizGrade1 * 0.5) + (quizGrade2 * 0.5));            
    double finalTest = (finalExam * 0.25);            
    double finalParticipationGrade = (participationGrades * 0.25);            
    double Overall = ( finalProjectGrade + finalQuizGrade + finalTest + finalParticipationGrade);            
    return Overall;
}
```

Comment: Unless @dlev solved the problem, you should tell us how it is not processing correctly.  Something like actual vs. expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you mean 0.05, not 0.5, for the quiz grades. Right now, you're giving them a weight of 50% each.

Comment: @dlev.... Thanks so much for pointing out that petty mistake that I made.  I even had the formula written down in front of me and couldn't make sense why it was giving me an average that didn't make since.  Thanks again.